# In react I had created wrapper components.So now i need to use them in my app.tsx in element parameter which is in route tag.But error as not jsx elem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

'Catalog' cannot be used as a JSX component.
Its return type 'CatalogState' is not a valid JSX element.
Type 'CatalogState' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, any>': type, props, keyts(2786)

here catalog is my wrapper component
THIS IS THE ROUTE PART WHERE I AM USING CATALOG AS A WRAPPER COMPONENT

```
<Routes>
       {/* <Route path={BASE}/></Catalog> */}
        {/* <Route path={BASE} element={<PrimeCatalogContainer/>} /> */}
        <Route path={BASE} element={()=>(<Catalog><PrimeCatalogContainer/></Catalog>)}/>
        <Route path={PRIME_CATALOG} element={<PrimeCatalogContainer />} />
        <Route path={PRIME_TRAINING} element={<PrimeTrainingPage />} />
        <Route path={PRIME_INSTANCE} element={<PrimeInstancePage />} />
        <Route path={PRIME_ALMPROFILE} element={<ALMProfilePage />} />
        <Route 
          path={PRIME_BOARDPAGE}
          element={<PrimeCommunityBoardPage />}
        />
        <Route
          path={PRIME_BOARDLIST}
          element={<PrimeCommunityBoardList />}
        />
    </Routes>
```

CATALOG COMPONENT

```
import { PrimeCatalogContainer } from "./almLib";
const Catalog = () =>{
  return(
    <>
    <div
        className="catalog_container"
        data-show-filters="true"
        data-show-search="true"
        data-catalogs="true"
        data-lo-types="true"
        data-skill-name="true"
        data-lo-format="true"
        data-duration="true"
        data-price="true"
        data-skills-level="true"
        data-learner-state="true"
        data-tag-name="true"
        data-skill-level="true"><PrimeCatalogContainer/>
     </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

instead of above catalogcomponent I tried below one also

```
import { PrimeCatalogContainer } from "./almLib";
  function Catalog (): JSX.Element {
    return(
        <div
        className="catalog__container"
        data-show-filters="true"
        data-show-search="true"
        data-catalogs="true"
        data-lo-types="true"
        data-skill-name="true"
        data-lo-format="true"
        data-duration="true"
        data-price="true"
        data-skills-level="true"
        data-learner-state="true"
        data-tag-name="true"
        data-skill-level="true"
      ><PrimeCatalogContainer/></div>
    );
 };
```

Comment: Hi! can you provide a code snippet to better see what could be happening? thanks

Comment: Please share relevant code snippet with proper information

Comment: You need to return a jsx element, on way is to wrap your component with fragment tag.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [docs](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/route), `element` should be a ReactNode, so instead of:

```js
<Route path={BASE} element={()=>(<Catalog><PrimeCatalogContainer/></Catalog>)}/>
```

you need to return the actual Catalog

```js
<Route path={BASE} element={<Catalog><PrimeCatalogContainer/></Catalog>}/>
```

Comment: yeah i tried with that also but didnt worked